# Constant BSOD after W10 1809 update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bsod

So, it took me almost 3 hours to update to 1809 and what happens? Blue screen of death!

Sometimes they appear right after I log in. Sometimes, when I run a program or a game.

When i try to use Google Chrome, it may close, crash the extensions or close + BSOD.

Tried uninstalling GPUs drivers and no difference...

I can't roll back because I had to delete the files (since it downloaded almost 20gb, I got almost no space left so I had to delete them).

Here are some of them:

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA (ntoskrnl.exe)

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA (win32kfull.sys)

QUOTA_UNDERFLOW

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (mtoskrnl.exe)

I can't even use my PC right now, had to ask this here with my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Your update went badly.
Unfortunately you will need some other working computer to help in recovery.

First, if you don't have backups to all your files, you may create a Linux live USB
and boot it in order to access your data and save it.

Second, create a boot USB for Windows 10 1809 and boot from it.
It should discover the existing Windows installation and "upgrade" it to itself,
perhaps fixing the problem on the way.

If this does not happen and the existing Windows installation is not detected,
then you need to install Windows from scratch and lose all settings and applications.
Prepare yourself for this by downloading all the drivers you need from
the manufacturer's website, and ensure that you have all the materials
required to reinstall the applications.

In the future, it is advisable before any major update of Windows to take
a disk image of the system disk and be capable of restoring it via a boot media,
just in case.